# Simultaneous equations in four variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm solving the following equations,
$$x+y=zw$$
$$z+w=xy$$
How many solutions $(x,y,z,w)$ exist, if the variables are reals?

Comment: Since your system is underdetermined, there will be infinitely-many solutions.

Comment: Of course, a priori, those infinitely many solutions could all be complex or at infinity (in projective space).

Comment: The same equations where one wants integer solutions appeared on this forum. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219762/ab-c-times-d-and-a-times-b-c-d/220512#220512

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving the 1st equation for $y$ and substituting in the second gives 
$$z+w=xzw-x^2\iff x^2-xzw+z+w=0$$
This equation has a solution for $x$ when
$$\Delta\ge 0\iff z^2w^2-4z-4w\ge 0$$
It remains to check that it always has solutions for $z,w$. Therefore, your system has an infinite number of solutions all of which satisfy:
$$z^2w^2-4z-4w\ge 0$$
$$x=\frac{zw-\sqrt{z^2w^2-4z-4w}}2$$
$$y=zw-x$$

Comment: oops... I think you meant $y = zw - x$ in your last line.

Comment: @ShaunAult Now fixed